# react-redux - value is not "up-to-date" in function

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-redux, paypal

Here is my situation: I'm implementing the payment provider PayPal in a software. I'm using React version 18.2 with the package @paypal/react-paypal-js and react-redux.

So far I have a component `selectPaymentProvider`, which is handling the payment procedure. Actually there will be only PayPal implemented yet. The complete component is too big to provide all code here, but here are the important parts:

This is how my component looks like:

```
function SelectPaymentProvider(props) {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const order = useSelector((state) => state.order.value);
    ...

    return (
        ...
        <PayPalScriptProvider options={initialOptions}>
            <PayPalButtons 
                style={{ layout: "horizontal", shape: "pill", color:"gold", label: 'paypal' }} 
                createOrder={(data, actions) => {
                    return actions.order.create({
                        purchase_units: getPurchaseData() 
                    })
                    .then((orderId) => {
                        createTransaction(orderId);
                        return orderId;
                    })
                    .catch((error) => {
                        console.log(error);
                    });
                }}
                onCancel={(data) => {
                    setIsTransactionCancelled(true);
                    sendStatusUpdate('transaction_cancelled', data.orderID);
                }}
                onError={(error) => {
                    setIsTransactionInProgress(false);
                    setHasErrorOccured(true);
                    setError(error.message);
                    sendStatusUpdate('transaction_error');
                }}
                onApprove={(data, actions) => {
                    return actions.order
                    .capture()
                    .then((transactionDetails) => {
                        if(transactionDetails.status === "COMPLETED") {
                            sendApprovedTransaction(transactionDetails);
                        }
                        else {
                            sendStatusUpdate('paypal_status_not_completed', transactionDetails.id);
                        }
                    });
                }}
            />
        </PayPalScriptProvider>
        ...
    )
}
```

By clicking on the PayPal button a new `orderID` is returned from PayPal (`createOrder`). This new `orderID` is given as parameter to the function `createTransaction`. This is the function:

```
function createTransaction(transactionId) {
    if(!isNullOrUndefined(transactionId)) {
        dispatch(setPaymentDetailsPaymentProviderTransactionId(transactionId));
        let formData = [
            {name: 'type', value: 'saveTransaction'},
            {name: 'order', value: JSON.stringify(order)},
            {name: 'team', value: JSON.stringify(team)},
            {name: 'transactionId', value: transactionId},
            {name: 'status', value: 'paypal_button_clicked'}
        ];
        fetchFromUrl(window.location.origin + '/setPaypalTransaction.asp','POST',formData);
    }
}
```

The first thing in the function is to store the provided `orderID` (in the function itself parameter `transactionId`) into the redux store. This works fine as you can see here:

[image]

So far so good.

As you can see in the code, the function `sendApprovedTransaction(transactionDetails)` is called when the transaction is approved and completed at PayPal. This is the `sendApprovedTransaction` function. It sends the data received from PayPal to our backend:

```
function sendApprovedTransaction(transactionDetails) {
    setIsTransactionInProgress(true);
    let formData = [
        {name: 'type', value: 'transactionApproved'},
        {name: 'order', value: JSON.stringify(order)},
        {name: 'transaction', value: JSON.stringify(transactionDetails)},
    ];
    fetchFromUrl(window.location.origin + '/setPaypalTransaction.asp','POST',formData)
    .then((result) => {
        if(result.data.success === false) {
            setHasErrorOccured(true);
            setIsTransactionInProgress(false);
            setError(result.data.errors);
            sendStatusUpdate('error_on_processing_transaction');
        }
        else {
            window.location.href = "/paymentcomplete";
        }
    })
    .catch((errors) => {
        setIsTransactionInProgress(false);
        setHasErrorOccured(true);
        setError(typeof(errors) === 'object' ? errors.message : errors);
        sendStatusUpdate('error_on_processing_transaction');
    });
}
```

Now I'm currently simulating an error from our backend when transaction is approved at PayPal. Therefore I'm returning a JSON array `{ success: false }`. This leads to, that the `catch` block of the function is being executed and the `catch` block calls at the end the function `sendStatusUpdate` with the parameter `error_on_processing_transaction`.

At this point is my issue now. This function should send a new status of the transaction to the backend. It has a second parameter `transactionId` which can be `null`. As you can see in the `catch` block, the function is being called without transactionId, because it is stored in the react-redux store.

```
function sendStatusUpdate(status, transactionId = null) {
    if(
        validPayPalStatuses.indexOf(status) > -1 && 
        (
            !isNullOrUndefined(order?.paymentDetails?.paymentProviderTransactionId) || 
            !isNullOrUndefined(transactionId)
        )
    ) {
        let formData = [
            {name: 'type', value: 'sendStatusUpdate'},
            {name: 'order', value: JSON.stringify(order)},
            {name: 'transactionId', value: ((transactionId === null) ? order.paymentDetails.paymentProviderTransactionId : transactionId)},
            {name: 'status', value: status}
        ];
        fetchFromUrl(window.location.origin + '/setPaypalTransaction.asp','POST',formData);
    }
    else {
        setHasErrorOccured(true);
        setError(getTextInLanguage('anErrorOccurredDuringPayment'));
    }
}
```

As written and shown above, I have stored the `transactionId` (or `orderID`) in the react-redux store. But the value of `order.paymentDetails.paymentProviderTransactionId` is always `null`.

[image]

I cannot see the reason, why it is suddenly `null` instead of the current transactionId. It does not seem to be an issue of react-redux. I also tested storing the transactionId by using a `useState` variable instead of storing the transactionId in react-redux. The result is the same. The `useState` variable was always `null`, too.

What can I try to resolve this?